# Cannot implicitly convert type NewDerivedClass to DerivedClass

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have existing code which has a Base class with some common properties and a derived class that has a few extra properties: Property1 & Property2.

I have the following function which populates some property details:

```
public void MyFunction(BaseClass base)
{ 
    var derivedClass = base as DerivedClass;

    derivedClass.Property1 = "blah";
    derivedClass.Property2 = "blahblah";
}
```

Now I have another new class **NewDerivedClass** that is also derived from BaseClass and need to modify the existing code to cope with this.

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
public void MyFunction(BaseClass base)
{ 
    var derivedClass = base as DerivedClass;

    if(SomeConditionTrue)
    {
        derivedClass = base as NewDerivedClass
    }

    derivedClass.Property1 = "blah";
    derivedClass.Property2 = "blahblah";
}
```

But I get the error: **Cannot implicitly convert type NewDerivedClass to DerivedClass.**

Ideally I would use generics like suggested here: [Cannot implicitly convert type 'customtype' to 'othercustomtype'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757858/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-customtype-to-othercustomtype) but there are too many places that I would have to modify code if I change the existing DerivedClass to use an interface.

Is there a way I can handle this converting to a different class if a condition is true.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem.  Does `NewDerivedClass` also happen to have some string-valued properties named `Property1` and `Property2`

Comment: Yes it does @dbc

Comment: So MyFunction can be called with either DerivedClass OR NewDerivedClass passed in as a paramater.  I need to somehow cope with this.

Comment: Do `DerivedClass` and `NewDerivedClass` both have `Property1` and `Property2` properties not defined on the base class?

Comment: Yes they do.  There are quite a few common properties I simplified the number for explanation purposes.

Comment: Can you create an interface containing the properties? Or add them to the base class?

Comment: I cannot add them to the base class (Not my code).  Creating an interface is an option yes but it requires lots of other code changes if I modify the initial DerivedClass to use an interface.

Comment: *Creating an interface is an option yes but it requires lots of other code changes* -- why is that?  Visual Studio can do it automatically, using [Extract Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-interface).

Comment: As soon as you're starting to do `if...` logic on your class hierarchy theres a fairly high chance your design is wrong. Rethink whether inheritance is the right pattern here.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you initially had a type hierarchy like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    // Many additional properties omitted.
}
```

You are now introducing a new derived class that happens to have identically named and properties, and you would like a clean way to work with both that avoids lots of copy/pasted code:

```
public class NewDerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; } 
    // Many additional properties omitted.
}
```

You have two options to do this.

**Firstly**, you could extract an intermediate class `IntermediateClass` to hold both properties, and insert it in the inheritance hierarchy like so:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public abstract class IntermediateClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : IntermediateClass 
{
}

public class NewDerivedClass : IntermediateClass 
{
}
```

Then in `MyFunction` check to see if the incoming object is of type `IntermediateClass` not `DerivedClass`.

**Secondly**, you could extract an interface, say `IHasDerivedProperties` and have both derived classes implement it.

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public interface IHasDerivedProperties
{
    string Property1 { get; set; }
    string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, IHasDerivedProperties
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class NewDerivedClass : BaseClass, IHasDerivedProperties
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Visual Studio's [**Extract Interface**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-interface) can make this change quite easily.

Then in `MyFunction` check to see if the incoming object is of type `IHasDerivedProperties` not `DerivedClass`.  With this design, you can also create methods that take either `DerivedClass` or `NewDerivedClass` by using [generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

```
public void MyFunction<TBaseClass>(TBaseClass derivedClass) 
    where TBaseClass : BaseClass, IHasDerivedProperties
{ 
    derivedClass.Property1 = "blah";
    derivedClass.Property2 = "blahblah";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have one parent `base` and two children `DerivedClass` and `NewDerivedClass` which are unrelated. As there is no inheritance between the two children, you can't cast one type in the other type. There is no `is a` relation between these siblings.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the C# 7´s is-expression with type pattern

```
public void MyFunction(BaseClass baseClass)
{ 
    if(baseClass is DerivedClass derivedClass)
    {
        derivedClass.Property1 = "blah";
        derivedClass.Property2 = "blahblah";
    }
    else if(baseClass is NewDerivedClass newDerivedClass)
    {
        newDerivedClass.Property1 = "blah";
        newDerivedClass.Property2 = "blahblah";
    }
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few common properties I simplified the number for explanation purposes.  I was hoping to avoid copy and paste of similar code but it looks in this case I cant avoid it???

Comment: @HarryBoy set the common properties before you do the casting then

Answer (score 1):

Your two derived classes might share a base class, but they are not the same, even if they have the same properties. Imagine you have this structure:

```
public class Mammal
{
 //some properties & methods
}

public class Lion : Mammal
{
   void Roar()
   {
   }
}

public class Tiger : Mammal
{
   void Roar()
   {
   }
}
```

Both lions and tigers roar, but are lions tigers? No.

So, what you need to do in this case is create a new instance of NewDerivedClass on if(SomeConditionTrue) and set its properties.

```
public void MyFunction(BaseClass base)
{ 

if(SomeConditionTrue)
{
    var newDerivedClass = base as NewDerivedClass;
    newDerivedClass.Property1 = "blah";
    newDerivedClass.Property2 = "blahblah";
}
else
{
    var derivedClass = base as DerivedClass;
    derivedClass.Property1 = "blah";
    derivedClass.Property2 = "blahblah";
}


}
```