# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'GameMaster'?

Tags: c#

I have this error in my script, and I've looked at other threads with the same problem but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here's my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameMaster : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GameMaster gm;

    void Start() {
        if (gm == null)
            gm = GameObject.FindWithTag("GM");
    }
 

    public Transform PlayerPrefab;
    public Transform SpawnPoint;

    public void RespawnPlayer () {
        Instantiate (PlayerPrefab, SpawnPoint.position, SpawnPoint.rotation);
    }

    public static void KillPlayer(Player player) {
        Destroy (player.gameObject);
        gm.RespawnPlayer();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot implicitly convert type 'customtype' to 'othercustomtype'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757858/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-customtype-to-othercustomtype)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast all object of different types to given type (assuming the can be of this given type)

```
Boo Foo = (Boo)GetMyObject();

public Poo GetMyObject()...
```

In this case (assuming `GameMaster` is a MonoBehaviour) you cannot make such a cast. You need to use `GetComponent` method on a GameObject.

```
void Start() 
{
    if (gm == null)
        gm = GameObject.FindWithTag("GM").GetComponent<GameMaster>();
}
```